# Read a file from resources folder JAVA

Tags: java, maven, resources

I want to get a file from the resource file, and to use it in string.

[image: My folder]

I tried this :

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("/resources/fileC.p12").getFile());

String data = String.valueOf(file);
```

but doesnt work, thanks for helping

I tried this but i had a error, it returns a null value

Comment: try `classLoader.getResource("fileC.p12")`. The directory ./src/main/resources of a Maven project is mapped to the root-level of the generated artifact (jar, war, etc.).

Comment: And getFile() won't work if the file is actually inside a jar/war/etc. Effectively the code you write may only work when running it from the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

`new File` In java, `File` means **File**. As in, an actual file on your actual harddisk. Resources **aren't** - they are entries in a jarfile and therefore not a file. Simply put, resources **cannot be read this way**.

Fortunately, File in general is barking up the wrong tree: The correct abstraction is `InputStream` or similar - that represents 'any stream of bytes'. A file can be an InputStream. So can a network socket, a blob from a network, or, indeed, a resource being streamed to you by the classloader, which could very well be getting it from a network or generating it whole cloth - classloaders can do that. It's an abstract mechanism.

You're also doing it wrong - you want `Type.class.getResource`. Your way is needlessly wordy and will fail in exotic scenarios (such as bootloaders and agents and the like, which have no classloader).

```java
class Example {
  public String getDataFromFileC() throws IOException {
    try (var in = Example.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/fileC.p12")) {
      return new String(in.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
  }
}
```

This:

- Uses `getResourceAsStream` which gives you an inputstream. As I mentioned, if you mention `File`, you lose. Hence, we don't.
- Uses the proper form: `MyType.class.get`. This avoids issues when subclassing or in root classloader situations.
- `MyType.class.get` needs a leading slash. the `getResource` on classloaders requires you *not* to have it (which explains why your snippet wouldn't work in any scenario - that leading slash).
- Uses try-with-resources as you should.
- Propagates exceptions as you should.
- Configures charset which you should do anytime you go from bytes to strings or vice versa.

NB: Depending on your build system, it may package those resources in the jar as `/fileC.p12` and not as `/resources/fileC.p12` - in fact, that is likely. You may want to update this to `"/fileC.p12"`.

NB2: `String.valueOf(file);` does not read files. It just calls `toString()` on the file object which gives you a path. Resources don't have to be a path so this cannot work. They do have a URL, which may or may not be useful. If you want that: `return MyClass.class.getResource("/resources/fileC.p12").toString();`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String data = new String(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fileC.p12").readAllBytes());
```

Your resource (which shouldn't be seen as a file as it could and probably should be packaged with your app) is at the root, so useful to start with '/' then it can be addressed from any package. Be cautious with Java >= 17 as that will be decoded by default as UTF-8, so if that's not the encoding, you will have to specify what is in the `String` ctor. It might be safer to do that anyway.